# Occurrence of っ in verb stems

Tags: verbs, etymology

Today when I came across the verb [訴]{うった}える in a sentence somewhere, it suddenly hit me that I don't very often see verbs like that: ones that have a sokuon (little っ) in their stem. The only verbs that come to my mind are ones of the type ホッとする、[発展]{はってん}する、[決定]{けってい}する et cetera, i.e. verbs that stem from a noun.

It so happens that the noun 訴え is the heart of 訴える so this verb, though not ending in する, also belongs to that category of verbs stemming from nouns.

**My question is the following**: Are there verbs that do contain this little っ in their stem, but do *not* derive from some noun? Even more strongly, could you state as a rule that a っ does *not* occur in the stem of a (let me just call it) "pure" verb?

I would be interested in reading more on origins of Japanese verbs, so any recommendations on this are also very welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some "pure"(?) verbs that include っ in their stem:

- いらっしゃる　←いらせらる
- 仰る（おっしゃる）　←おおせある
- 尊ぶ（たっとぶ）　←たふとぶ
- 則る（のっとる）　←のりとる
- 欲する（ほっする）　←ほりす

According to デジタル大辞泉, these are simply lexicalized euphonic changes of archaic verbs. 訴える was originally [うるたふ](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%86).

If you can include compound verbs and verbs with intensifier prefixes, many verbs contain っ. To list a few:

- 乗っ取る
- かっ飛ぶ、すっ飛ぶ、ぶっ飛ぶ、吹っ飛ぶ
- はっ倒す
- 引っこ抜く、引っ張る、引っ付く、引っかける
- くっつく、突っつく、せっつく
- ぶっ放す、ぶっ倒す、ぶっ殺す、ぶっ刺す、ぶっちぎる

Answer (score 10):

訴{うった}える does not derive from noun 訴{うった}え, but rather the opposite -- the noun 訴{うった}え derives from verb 訴{うった}える, as the stem or continuative form of the verb.

In turn, 訴{うった}える comes from older classical form 訴{うった}ふ.  This was a 下{しも}二段{にだん}活用{かつよう}動詞{どうし}, or "lower bigrade conjugation verb".  The "lower" part refers to the vowel of the stem, and "bigrade" means that there were two different vowel endings.  For 下{しも} verbs, these vowel endings were *‑u* and *‑e*.  ([JA Wikipedia article here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8).)  This contrasted with 上{かみ}二段{にだん}活用{かつよう}動詞{どうし}, for which the two vowel endings were *‑u* and *‑i*.  ([JA Wikipedia article here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8).)  Over time (some time around the [Muromachi period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muromachi_period), 1336–1573) both bigrade forms collapsed to unigrade forms, losing the *‑u* verb-stem endings to just have *‑e* for 下{しも} verbs like 訴{うった}ふ (now 訴{うった}える) and 食{た}ぶ (now 食{た}べる), and to just have *‑i* for 上{かみ} verbs like 落{お}つ (now 落{お}ちる) and 過{す}ぐ (now 過{す}ぎる).

Looking back further, 訴{うった}ふ got its geminated *‑tt‑* as a phonological contraction or erosion of older form 訴{うるた}ふ, which was apparently the form in use in the early [Heian period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heian_period) (794–1185).

I cannot find much beyond this point in history to divine the verb's derivation any further.  This verb *urutapu* is long enough to suggest a compound derivation, but I cannot find any clear roots.  The verb ending in classical Japanese and earlier was ふ, a common auxiliary verb used to indicate repeated action or ongoing state, but this only attached to the incomplete form (未然形{みぜんけい}) of the preceding verb, and I cannot find any clear indication of an ancient verb *urutu*.  The last two morae, たふ, could have been ancient verb 給{た}ふ used as an honorific auxiliary, but this only attached to the continuative form of a verb, and うる does not conform to continuative conjugation patterns.  The underlying ultimate derivation appears to be lost in time.

(**Note:** Shogakukan's big 国語{こくご}大{だい}辞典{じてん} is my primary source.)

Comment: Wow, so this っ in 訴える　can be traced back as far as to the Heian period - that's quite extraordinary. I think I might start saving some money to buy a 大辞典 myself... Thank you so much for this detailed response, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Some verbs in past tense include a little っ, such as 勝った, 持った, 取った, 蹴った, etc.

Other examples would be:
持っていく(もっていく), いらっしゃる, 張っ倒す(はったおす), 引っ越す(ひっこす), etc.